# MultiValueDictKeyError when trying to upload a file / no console output with print

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am just getting started with Django and I am trying to get a simple file upload to work.

After I select a file and submit it I get this error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /upload/

'document'
```

This is the simple code I wrote:

My upload.html

```
{%  block content %}
    <h2>Upload</h2>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/from-data">
        {%  csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="document">
        <button type="submit">Upload file</button>
    </form>
{%  endblock %}
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        print("TEST")
return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

Also I added the "upload" path to urls.py

A different problem is that I do not know why I cannot see the output of the print command from views.py anywhere.

Greets,
Tim

Comment: As per "I cannot see the output of the print" where do you expect to see it?

Comment: I am using PyCharm and I am used to it showing the print outputs in the console at the bottom.

Comment: Right, I suggest you take a look at how to debug your application using `pydevd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo `from-data` should be `form-data`